# wordpress injection theme not working anymore

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, eval

I have a website using twenty ten theme but recently ive got tons of eval injections and now i cant access the site anymore. I get

```
/** 
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads 
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme. * 
 * @package WordPress 
 */ 

/** 
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it. * 
 * @var bool 
 */ 

define('WP_USE_THEMES', true); 
/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */ 
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
```

You can see it at: http://wellnesste.com
I have cleaned all the malicious code but still the same, any ideas?

index.php

```
> <?php     
/**

 * The main template file.

 *

 * This is the most generic template file in a WordPress theme

 * and one of the two required files for a theme (the other being style.css).

 * It is used to display a page when nothing more specific matches a query.

 * E.g., it puts together the home page when no home.php file exists.

 * Learn more: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

 *

 * @package WordPress

 * @subpackage Twenty_Ten

 * @since Twenty Ten 1.0

 */



get_header(); ?>


    <div id="container">

        <div id="content" role="main">





        <? /* Run the loop to output the posts.

         * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file

         * called loop-index.php and that will be used instead.

         */

         get_template_part( 'loop', 'index' );



        </div><!-- #content -->

    </div><!-- #container -->
?>
```

Comment: Come on no help? how do i get rid of the error when accessing the site? really ran out of options after 2 hours of googleing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your index.php document is missing php wrappers:

```
<?php

//code

?>
```

Either that or php is not running your server.

Comment: not missing and php is running..

Comment: are you sure? when I view the source of http://wellnesste.com/ they're missing. Try adding a phpinfo.php file in your site root, and with the following code inside: <?php phpinfo(); ?>. Then go to http://wellnesste.com/phpinfo.php. That will confirm that php is running.

Comment: i have updated the index.php just to be sure and still the problem remains. you can see the code at http://jsfiddle.net/HynhF/  also please see: http://wellnesste.com/phpinfo.php cheers

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean twentyten's index.php, I meant your Wordpress root's index.php. Or whichever file starts like this: `Front to the WordPress application...`. That file seems to be faulty. If it isn't, verify that your .htaccess file is correct too, if in doubt replace with the default one.

Comment: great, i dont know how i missed the root file..thank so much. now if you have any idea how to track the vulnerability used to inject eval between <?php wrappers... ? :)

Comment: haha, that's a beast of a different nature. I know there are a ton of good resources out there. Try asking your hosting company too, as they can trace the culprits and their shenanigans through the access logs.

Comment: thanks alot man, appreciate!